# how to export the dashboard to excel report at power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm new at the Power BI.

I created dashboard on Power BI and I have published to the web
when opening the dashboard  on custom URL I need to export the dashboard to excel report
can I do this in Power BI or not

I new I can to do this in Power BI web APP but I need do that in my dashboard URL

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This "custom URL" that you mention makes me think that you used [`Publish to web`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web). One of the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web#limitations) of this feature is that you can't export the data:

> - Reports using row level security.
> - Reports using any Live Connection data source, including Analysis Services Tabular hosted on-premises, Analysis Services Multidimensional, and Azure Analysis Services.
> - Reports shared to you directly or through an organizational content pack.
> - Reports in a group in which you are not an edit member.
> - "R" Visuals are not currently supported in Publish to web reports.
> - **Exporting Data from visuals in a report, which has been published to the web.**
> - ArcGIS Maps for Power BI visuals.
> - Reports containing report-level DAX measures.
> - Single sign-on data query models.
> - Secure confidential or proprietary information.
> - The automatic authentication capability provided with the Embed option doesn't work with the Power BI JavaScript API. For the Power BI JavaScript API, use the user owns data approach to embedding.

You can [vote](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/12275796-export-to-excel-tiles-of-published-to-web-report) for this feature though.

Comment: thank you for this information, I have a small inquiry is there any way to export my dashboard to excel after published it

Comment: You can export data behind a visual to CSV or Excel, but there are many limitations. It's better to do this from you data source, not from the report. To export the data of a visual, click the ellipsis in the top right corner and select `Export`. If you share it in the normal way (button `Share` in the toolbar above, requires Pro accounts for you and the people you share with), then your colleagues will be able to export the data too.